# PHP+javascript Input URL parsing

Tags: php, url

So i need users to provide URLs to their websites...

Through testing they typically are submitted in these forms:

1. http://www.domain.com/page.html
2. www.domain.com/page.html
3. <a href="http://www.domain.com/page.html">http://www.domain.com/page.html</a>
4. https://www.domain.com/page.html

with variations on the actual url, that fit mostly within the URL spec:
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

I want to store the URLs in form 1/4 with the protocol intact, i guess if no protocol is defined i will use http.

is there a strategy that i could potentially provide an efficient conversion besides trying to determine which form is input, then trying to convert it?

Comment: Form 1/4 looks the same as form 3/4 to me

Comment: different protocols, the point was i needed to keep the protocol info

Comment: Edited to fix case 3, <html> formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this, is using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html). The php code:

```
$text = "FTP Source: ftp://ftp.testftp.com/ - 
        My mail adress is name@yahoo.com and 
        I love www.facebook.com/ 
        I search things using http://www.google.fr/";
$urlRegularExpression = "/([fhtps]*:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/";
preg_match_all($urlRegularExpression, $text, $urls);
print_r($urls);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array //THE WHOLE RESULTS
        (
            [0] =>  'ftp://ftp.testftp.com'
            [1] =>  'www.facebook.com'
            [2] =>  'http://www.google.fr'
        )

    [1] => Array //THE PROTOCOLS USED (ftp, http, sftp, https)
        (
            [0] => 'ftp://'
            [1] => ''
            [2] => 'http://'
        )

    [2] => Array //THE ADRESS WITHOUT PROTOCOL
        (
            [0] => 'ftp.testftp.com'
            [1] => 'www.facebook.com'
            [2] => 'www.google.fr'
        )

)
```

EDIT:
You can move the ) before :// in the regular expression to get only the protocol name:

```
$urlRegularExpression = "/([fhtps]*):\/\/?([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/";
```

Example: http:// -> http

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i needed, i have irrational fear of regex!

Comment: I also had that "irrational fear of regex" :). I can recommend you some material to understand them once for all, very well explained on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRR9fOXkfRE . There are 3 parts. I recommend all of them! Good luck!

Comment: i ended up using:
/([fhtps]*)[:\/]*([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/

as i wanted the protocol separate, but the :\/\/ caused it not to match, when they didn't include the ://

Answer (score 0):

Since there's really only 1 format out of the 4 above that you would want to change, you can use the below

```
$x = "www.domain.com/page.html";
if(strpos($x, "http") === false){
    $x = "http://".$x;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_url = "www.domain.com/page.html"; // User submitted URL
$enhanced_url = substr($user_url , strpos($user_url,".") + 1 );
```

This will return the domain.com/page.html in all cased you've mentioned